# "Type 'Object' is not assignable to type" with new HttpClient / HttpGetModule

Tags: angular, api, http-get

Following [Google's official Angular 4.3.2 doc here](https://angular.io/guide/http), I was able to do a simple `get` request from a local json file. I wanted to practice hitting a real endpoint from JSON placeholder site, but I'm having trouble figuring out what to put in the `.subscribe()` operator. I made an `IUser` interface to capture the fields of the payload, but the line with `.subscribe(data => {this.users = data})` throws the error `Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'IUser[]'`. What's the proper way to handle this? Seems pretty basic but I'm a noob.

My code is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IUsers } from './users';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-http',
  templateUrl: './http.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./http.component.css']
})
export class HttpComponent implements OnInit {
  productUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  users: IUsers[];
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this._http.get(this.productUrl).subscribe(data => {this.users = data});
  }

}
```

Comment: Because data has not the type IUsers, try this `.subscribe((data: IUsers) => ...` or  `this.users = data as any;`

Comment: Thank you @cyrix . `data as any` did the trick in my case.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You actually have a few options here, but use generics to cast it to the type you're expecting.

```
   // Notice the Generic of IUsers[] casting the Type for resulting "data"
   this.http.get<IUsers[]>(this.productUrl).subscribe(data => ...

   // or in the subscribe
   .subscribe((data: IUsers[]) => ...
```

Also I'd recommend using async pipes in your template that auto subscribe / unsubscribe, especially if you don't need any fancy logic, and you're just mapping the value.

```
users: Observable<IUsers[]>; // different type now

this.users = this.http.get<IUsers[]>(this.productUrl);

// template:
*ngFor="let user of users | async"
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm on the Angular doc team and one open todo item is to change these docs to show the "best practice" way to access Http ... which is through a service.

Here is an example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private _productUrl = './api/products/products.json';

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl)
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        let errorMessage = '';
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
        } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
        }
        console.error(errorMessage);
        return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

The component would then look like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Comment: Just started your course! I'll refactor my code into services to follow best practices!

Comment: Great! Just FYI ... the course currently uses the old Http Service. We are working on an update now.

Comment: Roger that, I'm trying to figure it out on my own as an exercise :P

Comment: Quick question, what's the reason to typcast api url after http.get? I tried it without, and it still returns proper data.

Comment: I noticed this as well. I assume it is because of the function return type we've defined. If we also remove that, then the data is just Observable(object). So it appears that we could go with either the typecast or the method return type. I like having both for clarity.

Comment: Inside the ngOnInit()'s .subscribe function, the first arrow function has curly braces, is that a style preference or making it into an object? MDN says statement or code blocks go in curly braces, but this one is an expression right?

Comment: I had more lines of code there which required the curly braces. I deleted the extra lines, but not the braces. I'll delete them to prevent any confusion.