# Mapping Jenkins JSON API in ANGULAR 5

Tags: json, angular, rest, rxjs, mapping

Using the Jenkins JSON API I'm correctly getting the following JSON result:

```
{"_class":"hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild","estimatedDuration":50136,"fullDisplayName":"JazzClub #26","result":"SUCCESS","timestamp":1524823606642}
```

To display the result in a Dashboard using a well working Angular 5 app I tried :

**MODEL**

```
export interface JenkinsBuild {
  _class: string;
  estimatedDuration: number;
  fullDisplayName: string;
  result: string;
  timestamp: number;
}
```

**Service**

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {JenkinsBuild} from '../Model/jenkinsBuild';


@Injectable()
export class JenkinsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getLastBuildInfos(): Observable<JenkinsBuild> {
    return this.http.get<JenkinsBuild>(AppComponent.Jenkins_API_URL +
      '/lastBuild/api/json?tree=result,timestamp,estimatedDuration,fullDisplayName,building');
  }


}
```

**Dashboard Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {JenkinsService} from '../Service/jenkinsService';
import {JenkinsBuild} from '../Model/jenkinsBuild';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jenkins',
  templateUrl: './jenkins.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jenkins.component.css']
})
export class JenkinsComponent implements OnInit {
  jenkinsDataStringified: any;
  jenkinsData: JenkinsBuild;

  constructor(public jenkinsService: JenkinsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jenkinsService.getLastBuildInfos().subscribe((data:JenkinsBuild) => {
      this.jenkinsData = data ;
    });
  }
}
```

**A simple Html display test**

```
<p>{{jenkinsData.result}}</p>
<p>{{jenkinsData.fullDisplayName}}</p>
```

I've tried to fix the mapping problems based 
on answers from here[Type assignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426907/type-object-is-not-assignable-to-type-with-new-httpclient-httpgetmodule)

But I'm still getting a browser console error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined.

Any Ideas remarks about the JSON mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the safe navigation operator (notice the `?` after `jenkinsData`) - [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

```
<p>{{jenkinsData?.result}}</p>
<p>{{jenkinsData?.fullDisplayName}}</p>
```

This is needed because your HTML is loaded before the the async called has returned, which means that `jenkinsData` is undefined until that function returns.

Comment: Using safe navigation operator is one way to handle this kind of issues. In this case other parts of the page may be shown without the data which will be available after a short delay. But if you want to load the page after the whole data is arrived, then use Resolve instead: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve