# res.json() HttpClient Response

Tags: json, angular, httpclient, response

I realize that the new updates don't require conversion of a response to JSON.

The tutorial I am following puts this into the api.service.ts

```typescript
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  messages = []
  getMessage(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/newroute').subscribe(res =>{
      this.messages = res.json()
    })
  }

}
```

However, with the new update, "res.json()" does not work. I get the following error: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.

How can I solve this?

Here is the data I'm trying to loop through:

```
var posts = [
{message:'Hello World'},
{greeting:'Whats going on'}
]
```

Comment: It seems your res is an object and not an array. Just show the console.loh(res)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005430/property-json-does-not-exist-on-type-object)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
getMessage(){
  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/newroute').subscribe(res =>{
  this.messages = res;
  })
}
```

Comment: I get this error for 'this.messages': The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Comment: I guess this would help you more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426907/type-object-is-not-assignable-to-type-with-new-httpclient-httpgetmodule

Comment: @amihac Putting `any` could be quick fix but I suggest you to go through above mentioned link in my comments

Comment: @amihac did u get the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular allows you to do [type checking on the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response). You don't have to manually parse JSON.

Here is a code snippet from your example (I recommend using types):

```
messages: Message[] = []
getMessage() {
  this.http.get<Message[]>('http://localhost:3000/newroute').subscribe((res: Message[]) => {
    this.messages = res;
  });
}
```

(Update)

Based on your provided data, an interface for Message could look like this:

```
export interface Message {
  [s: string]: string;
}
```

However, if "Messages" can only have specific keys like "message" and "greeting", then you can add any of those as optional properties as well.

```
export interface Message {
  message?: string;
  greeting?: string;
}
```

Comment: I get this error for 'this.messages': The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Comment: It depends on what type of data you are returning. If you update your question with a sample of return data, I can update the answer to help you more accurately

Comment: Added to the question! 

var posts = [
{message:'Hello World'},
{greeting:'Whats going on'}
]

Comment: Actually, did you mean the error is on this line `messages: Message[] = []` or this line `this.messages = res;`?

Comment: @amihac I updated the answer to also include the return type being passed in as a generic on the `http.get` method. Your issue may be a combination of this and/or res not having a type specified `.subscribe((res: Message[]) =>` instead of `.subscribe(res =>`.

Comment: THANK YOU! Including the type Message[] worked! Thank you! @OneLunch Man

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't forget to mark as answer if this solved your problem-

Answer (score -1):

HttpClient gives you json object only, so no need to do .json() again.So do the following code it works for you

```
getMessage(){
  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/newroute').subscribe(res =>{
  let messages: any = res;
  this.messages = messages;
  })
}
```